# ¿Cómo poder restar filas en pares de una columna en especifico en un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Es decir, lo que tengo que hacer es restar las fechas en pares, restar la fila 1 con la fila 2, fila 3 con la 4... y ese resultado almacenarlo en una nueva columna utilizando segundos como unidades, posteriormente, una vez obtenidos esos tiempos, agruparlos y sumarlos por su respectivo nombre.

Intente implementarlo con el metodo `diff` utilizando df['Diff_time'] = df['Time'].diff(periods=-1).dt.seconds` el problema es que me resta las filas una por una, es decir, fila1-fila2, fila2-fila3 y así sucesivamente.

```
 #Importar librerias 
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

# Direccion del archivo xlsx
path = ("C:\\Users\\braya\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Algoritmo y Metodologia\\ejemplo")

# Lectura del archivo
df = pd.read_excel("tiempos.xlsx") 

# Algoritmo
# Conversion de string a datetime
df['Tiempo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tiempo'])
df['Diff_time'] = 
df['Tiempo'].diff(periods=-1).dt.seconds  

# Exportar archivo formato excel 
df.to_excel("tiempos_exp.xlsx", index = False) 
#df.info()
```

El archivo de excel que tengo es parecido a esta tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, sin que pongas tu `dataframe` en forma de texto y un ejemplo de la información de lo que esperas obtener es muy difícil que imaginemos lo que quieres hacer. Además, es necesario que agregues tu código, de otra forma tu pregunta va a terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Puedes hacer algo un poco raro. Primero filtras las columnas pares y luego splicas el código que ya tienes

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @bragrota, la respuesta que puse realiza lo que pides, o ¿Hay algo que no funcione de forma correcta?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato exacto, la respuesta que pusiste ya realiza la resta de las filas, solo que al momento de agruparlo por nombre, no lo hace, agrupa todos los tiempos, sin importar el nombre.

Comment: @bragrota, ¿Cómo estás agrupando? ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que falta?

Comment: @bragrota, wow, ya vi que editaste tu pregunta pero ahora es totalmente diferente a lo que solicitaste, es tan diferente que ahora parece que la respuesta que puse no tiene sentido a lo que preguntaste originalmente, eso no está bien. La pregunta original era poder hacer resta condicional de filas, esta nueva pregunta debería ser una nueva publicación ya que es totalmente diferente a la petición original

Comment: Lo mejor sería que pusieras tu pregunta tal como estaba antes de esta última edición y únicamente agregar una imagen con el formato del `dataframe` del grupo como lo necesitas

Comment: Has modificado radicalmente la pregunta haciendo que la respuesta y comentarios queden fuera de lugar. Te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta

Comment: @bragrota , si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta por favor acéptala, de esa forma ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Ya que no agregaste los datos a tu pregunta cree un ejemplo genérico

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'fechas': ['2022/04/20 08:00:00', '2022/04/20 18:00:00', '2022/04/20 10:00:00', '2022/04/20 18:00:00', '2022/04/20 11:00:00', '2022/04/20 18:00:00', '2022/04/20 12:00:00', '2022/04/20 18:00:00']})

df['fechas']= pd.to_datetime(df['fechas'])
```

Esto crea el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    fechas
0   2022-04-20 08:00:00
1   2022-04-20 18:00:00
2   2022-04-20 10:00:00
3   2022-04-20 18:00:00
4   2022-04-20 11:00:00
5   2022-04-20 18:00:00
6   2022-04-20 12:00:00
7   2022-04-20 18:00:00
```

Puedes generar dos grupos con filas pares e impares utilizando el método `iloc()` Nota: ya que no agregaste tus datos, en el ejemplo genérico solo hay una columna así que tendrás que adaptar el código para tus datos

```
df1 = df.iloc[[i for i in range(len(df.index)) if i%2 == 0],0]
df2 = df.iloc[[i for i in range(len(df.index)) if i%2 == 1],0]
```

Luego reinicializamos los índices para poder restar los dos grupos

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Y para finalizar realizamos la resta

```
(df2-df1).dt.seconds
```

Esto devuelve

```
0    36000
1    28800
2    25200
3    21600
Name: fechas, dtype: int64
```

Comment: No se refiere a restar pares con impares, sino restar todas las filas pares de un dataframe, por ejemplo `fila2-fila4` y así.

Comment: @Christian, Según el primer párrafo de la pregunta dice restar 1 con 2, 3 con 4 y así "Es decir, lo que tengo que hacer es restar las fechas en pares, restar la fila 1 con la fila 2, y ese resultado almacenarlo en una nueva columna con segundos, posteriormente, restar la fila 3 con la 4 y así sucesivamente..."

Comment: Pero se contradice con lo que dice al último: "el problema es que me resta las filas una por una, es decir, fila1-fila2, fila2-fila3 y así sucesivamente" ._.

Comment: Exacto, lo que está sucediendo actualmente es que resta cada fila con la anterior, pero el OP quiere es que se hagan "grupos" o "pares" de filas y únicamente se haga la resta en esos grupos o pares, por eso especificó que la fila 1 con la 2, la 3 con la 4

Comment: Es decir, actualmente se está generando una resta más de lo deseado, la fila 3 con la 2 no es deseada, por eso es necesario separar en grupos de filas pares con impares y luego hacer la resta

Comment: A shap, ya lo vi bien. Lo siento me equivoqué, mejor me voy a dormir